# Human sport sounds and vocalisations

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, sound-effects-recording, sound-libraries, sport

I'm working on a project at the moment that requires some human sport sounds such as tennis grunts, footballers calling to each other, heavy panting, those kind of things. Any sporting vocalizations really

Tried recording quite a few but didn't come out so well. Was wondering if anyone has anything like this or knows any good SFX libraries that might be of use?

Any tips much appreciated!
David

Comment: Seems like you could just google "sport sound effect library" and get tons of options.

Comment: hi todd, well yes, but i think what asks for is fairly specific, not just sport sounds like balls bouncing etc. he could waste a lot of time scourint the results for something that might need a different search term. 
human vocalisations are very expressive and some recordings just don't work in some cases/scenes. 
@david: please provide a list of specific sounds, like grunts, and the variations you need. it makes it easier for anyone to answer your question.